Ganache alternative in docker
After the Sunset of Truffle and Ganache . Are they already some alternative to the Ganache docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/trufflesuite/ganache with enabled persistent data for local development and testing ?
Ganache is an awesome tool. I wish they had continued maintaining it even without Truffle...
Thank you.

I ended up using Geth in dev mode with persistence storage.
docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  geth-dev:
    image: ethereum/client-go:v1.14.3
    volumes:
      - ./genesis.json:/root/genesis.json
      - ./init-geth.sh:/init-geth.sh
      - geth-data:/dev-chain
    ports:
      - "8545:8545"
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "/init-geth.sh"]

volumes:
  geth-data:


the init-geth.sh file
#!/bin/sh

# Initialize
if [ ! -d /dev-chain/geth ]; then
  geth --dev --datadir /dev-chain init /root/genesis.json
fi

# Start
exec geth --dev --datadir /dev-chain --networkid 1337 --http --http.addr "0.0.0.0" --http.api "admin,eth,debug,miner,net,txpool,personal,web3" --http.corsdomain "*" --http.vhosts "*" --verbosity 4

The gensis.json file is a default one. I just added a new allocated address with balance.
 ...
 "alloc": {
     "0xyour-address": {
         "balance": "0x111111111111113332222"
     },

I run it with docker-compose up -d
I could remove the container but keep the volumes. If I want to delete everything including the state of the Blockchain I run docker-compose down -v

You can Use Remix IDE online or locally which comes with its own EVM emulator, or use Hard Hat as EVM emulator which is easy to dockerize.

thank you , not the answer I was looking for :) I'm looking from something official, supported and well documented :)
